# Why is regression analysis also statistical test?

Tags: statistics, regression

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis), regression analysis is a statistical process for estimating the relationships among variables. Regression analysis is widely used for prediction and forecasting. So why is regression analysis also used as statistical test? For example, in [this page](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/whatstat/), logistic regression and linear regression are listed among t-test, ANOVA, chi-square test etc.

Answer (score 1):

On my viewpoint, regression analysis is a mathematical tool which can be used in various circonstances and for various kind of problems. Of course, in many statistical problems a regression technic is currently used. But they are also problems involving regressions where nothing is randomly specified and where no statistics are needed.
A mathematical tool on one hand and mathematical or physical problem on the other hand, are two different thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Regression analysis is surely an important tool for prediction and forecasting, but it is also commonly used as a statistical test for many purposes, e.g. to  investigate whether a given variable is associated with another one independently of confounders, or whether a given multivariable model significantly predicts a given variable, and so on. In all these applications, regression provides a number of parameters, including measures of the strength of these associations and corresponding p values. In this view, it is one of the most important statistical tests used in many fields of sciences.